# How to change the splash screen in the Android environment in IBM Worklight 6.0?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen

I want to change the IBM splash image that comes by default when I run the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Android environment in Worklight, the splash image is stored under: `native\res\drawable\splash.9.png`.

To replace it, simply:

1. Create your own splash image (make sure to follow [Google's 9patch guidelines](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for creating a splash image)
2. Place it under `nativeResources\res\drawable`

Upon building the application the image will replace the default provided image.

Comment: Hi Adar, i have a splash screen which has a text and a logo. If i use the 9 patch image. My text in the splash screen is not propotionate. In Very high definition device the text size is very small. I am trying to add different splash.png in various drawable folder in nativeResources, but Worklight environment always creates the splash.9 image with IBM logo and use it in the application. How to add custom splash screen for android and overside the 9patch image used by worklight.

Comment: Delete the splash.9.png from android\native\assets\... and Worklight's splash will not longer be displayed. As for different resolutions - this is not related to Worklight; consult with the Android documentation.

Comment: Thanks. My build process is completely automatic using Ant Task. My Native folder is created using AntTask and .APK will be created using the Ant Task. So i keep all my assets in Android Environment "nativeResources" folder. I deleted the splash.9 image from this folder. If i remove this file, Worklight added the default 9patch splash screen image with IBM logo. If i add my 9 patch splash image in nativeResources. Due to text content in the splash screen my text size is small in higher resolution devices.

Comment: I can't help you with 9patch - that is not Worklight technology, but Google's.